# How to run sqlite3 inline command using c#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, command-line, process

When I run the below command in cmd prompt of windows:

```
sqlite3 -header -csv local-DataBase.sqlite "select * from customers;" > data.csv
```

It creates a file called "data.csv" with the result of `"select * from customers;"` in it with headers.
I need to run the same command as above in c# so that it the console app creates a file for the result of the sql command.

Till now I have done this:

```
 string sqlLite3ExePath = "sqlite3";
 string sqLitePath2 = "-header -csv local-DataBase.sqlite \"select* from customers;\" > data.csv";

 using (Process pProcess = new Process())
                {
                    pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = sqlLite3ExePath;
                    pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = sqLitePath2 ;
                    pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    pProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                    pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                    pProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                    pProcess.Exited += PProcess_Exited;
                    pProcess.Start();
                    string output = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); 
                    pProcess.WaitForExit();    
                    Debug.WriteLine(output);
                }
```

But this throws an error:

```
Error: near ">": syntax error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `> data.csv` is a shell operation redirecting the output to a file, not an sqlite argument. The `output` string already contains that output. Try removing `> data.csv` completely and save the contents of `output` to a file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah but if I want to save the output using that same inline command inside "sqLitePath2" variable, how do I do that?

Comment: This is *two* commands, not one. If you want to do that, you need to start the shell (ie `cmd`) and pass the entire line as an argument. If you do that `pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` won't return anything

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thats alright. So for that  pProcess.StartInfo.FileName  will become cmd? and entire command as argument?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please give the exact solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are two things going on when you run this command from the command prompt, you're running SQLite, but because of the redirect operator, you're also having the shell capture the output and create a file for you.

If you want to recreate this exact behavior, you need to run the shell and pass it this command:

```csharp
    string sqlLite3ExePath = "cmd";
    string sqLitePath2 = "/c \"sqlite3 -header -csv local-DataBase.sqlite ^\"select* from customers;^\" > data.csv\"";

    using (var pProcess = new Process())
    {
        pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = sqlLite3ExePath;
        pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = sqLitePath2;
        pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        pProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        pProcess.Exited += PProcess_Exited;
        pProcess.Start();
        string output = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        pProcess.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
```